# How can i make a pdf file with all the data entered in html(HTML5)?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

How to add data to a pdf file with a click of a button without using java. Javascripts and other api's can be used. Please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it has worked good for me:**
http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf

Get it at:
http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/downloads/list

Demo:
http://jspdf.com/

**EDIT** - I have changed links for the better source...

Comment: well i will say that not a complete answer. I need data to be fetched from text boxes or radio buttons.

Comment: well I am saying that if you want to be smart please answer to peoples questions, also appreciate help from others.

Comment: well that is very much appreciated from my side. But my question is different from your answer . Hence ..